# Encoding and then decoding json with non-ascii characters in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, character-encoding

I have a python application that encodes some objects to json, passes the json string to another program, and then reads in a possibly modified version of that json string.

I need to check that what's changed with the json encoded objects. However, I'm having trouble with re-encoding non-ascii characters.  For example:

```
x = {'\xe2': None} # a dict with non-ascii keys
y = json.dumps(x,ensure_ascii=False)
y
#> '{"\xe2": null}'
```

works just fine, but when I try to load the json, I get:

```
json.loads(y)
#> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0
json.loads(y.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
#> "{u'': None}"
json.loads(y.decode('utf-8','replace'))
#> {u'\ufffd': None}
```

and unfortunately `'\xe2' in {u'\ufffd': None}` evaluates to `False`

I'm willing to bet there is a simple solution, but all my googling and searching on SO has failed to find an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to go to the thing that is generating this `dict` and properly encode things there as utf-8.  Currently, your keys are encoded as [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

```
print('\xe2'.decode('cp1252'))
â
```

If you can't fix at the source, you'll need to do some post-processing.

```
d = {'\xe2': None}

fixed_d = {k.decode('cp1252'):v for k,v in d.iteritems()}

json.dumps(fixed_d)
Out[24]: '{"\\u00e2": null}'

json_dict_with_unicode_keys = json.dumps(fixed_d)

json_dict_with_unicode_keys
Out[32]: '{"\\u00e2": null}'

print(json.loads(json_dict_with_unicode_keys).keys()[0])
â
```

(Some of the content of this answer assumes you're on python 2, there are differences in unicode handling in py3)