# How to decode json with non-ascii character?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a json file with non-ascii character in it. I'm trying to retrieve few fields that have non-ascii character but I'm getting key errors.

I tried this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444811/encoding-and-then-decoding-json-with-non-ascii-characters-in-python-2-7) but it didn't helped. I got `UnicodeEncodeError` error.

The JSON is:

```
{"Sh\u012bn\u1e0fan\u1e0f": "1","Shibirgh\u0101n": "2", "Khawr Fakk\u0101n": "3", "Sharjah": "4", "Ras al-Khaimah": "5", "Sang-e Ch\u0101rak": "6"}
```

My code:

```
my_dict.update({city.encode("utf-8"):id})
fobj = open("my.json",'a',0)        
json.dump(m_dict,fobj)
fobj.close()
```

To read the json:

```
with io.open('my.json',encoding='utf-8') as data_file:    
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
    print data[u"Shibirghān".encode("utf-8")]
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'Shibirgh\xc4\x81n
```

Comment: You don't need to do the encoding/decoding, use unicode and let the json module handle it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed all the encoding. It works now

Answer (score 0):

I try to repeat your error, but it seems not happened.

The following mock code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import simplejson as json

#id_dict = {"Sh\u012bn\u1e0fan\u1e0f": "1","Shibirgh\u0101n": "2", "Khawr Fakk\u0101n": "3", "Sharjah": "4", "Ras al-Khaimah": "5", "Sang-e Ch\u0101rak": "6"}

id_dict = {}
encoded_city = u"Shibirghān".encode('utf-8')
id_dict.update({encoded_city: 1})

with open('my.json', 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(id_dict, fp)

jsoned_id_dict = json.dumps(id_dict)
print 'jsoned_id_dict: ', jsoned_id_dict

with open('my.json', 'rb') as data_fp:
    data = json.load(data_fp)
    print 'result for key %s : %d ' % (u"Shibirghān", data[u"Shibirghān"])
```

And result is:

```
jsoned_id_dict:  {"Shibirgh\u0101n": 1}
result for key Shibirghān : 1
```

As jsoned result for "Shibirghān" is not same as in your question, I guess it may be related with other reason, other than json module

Please let me know if misunderstood ~_~

Comment: It was because of the encoding I was using while loading the json and using the encoded key to retrieve the file. I removed the encoding as suggested by @thebjorn and let the json module handle it. It works now.